# Variable coefficient wave equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$u_{tt} - f(x)^{2}u_{xx} + u_{t} = 0$$ for $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty)$ with $u(x, 0) = 0$ and $u_{t}(x,0) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, suppose there exists an $M$ such that $|f(x)|^{2} \leq M$ for all $x$. Must any smooth compactly supported solution $u$ be identically zero?

If we assume that $u_{xx}$ and $u_{t}$ are both always $\geq 0$, then we have the following solution. Since $u_{xx} \geq 0$, $$u_{tt} - Mu_{xx} + u_{t} \leq u_{tt} - f(x)^{2}u_{xx} + u_{t} = 0.$$ Let $E(t) := \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}Mu_{x}^{2} + u_{t}^{2}\, dx$. Then as $u_{t} \geq 0$,
$$\dot{E}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}u_{t}(u_{tt} - Mu_{xx})\, dx \leq -\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_{t}^{2}\, dx \leq 0.$$ Since $E(0) = 0$, it follow that $u$ is identically 0. Is there a way to get around the assumptions that $u_{xx}$ and $u_{t}$ are always $\geq 0$? If not, how else can one prove this problem?

Comment: Already $u_{xx}\ge 0$ implies $u\equiv 0$ (with no PDE involved) because if a function is convex (wrt $x$) and compactly supported, it has to be identically zero... I don't have a proof for your assertion, though I'm sure it's true. For a similar PDE $u_{tt}-(g(x)^2 u_x)_x + u_t=0$, the energy functional $\int u_t^2+g(x)^2 u_x^2$ does the job. Unfortunately, your PDE is in _non-divergence form_ $f(x)^2 u_{xx}$, and for those the energy methods are less suitable...